# Não atualiza valor

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

O Calculo e os valores me retorna tudo certo, porém na hora de sobrepor o valor anterior e adiciona o novo ele não altera, mantem o antigo.

Compra Controller:

```
public ActionResult Update(CompraModel viewModel)
        {
            var ConsultaAntigo = ckm.Compra(viewModel.Quant);
            var Antigo = ConsultaAntigo.Where(c => c.Id == c.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            var Consulta = ckm.ControleEstoque(viewModel.ProdutoId);
            var Estoque = Consulta.OrderBy(t => t.NomeProduto).FirstOrDefault();

            int AntigoFinal = Estoque.Quantidade - Antigo.Quant;

            Estoque.Quantidade = AntigoFinal;

            int quantidadefinal = Estoque.Quantidade + viewModel.Quant;

            Estoque.Quantidade = quantidadefinal;

            viewModel.VlrTotal = viewModel.VlrUnit * viewModel.Quant;

//-------------/\ Pega o valor antigo e retira do estoque /\-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Compra compra = viewModel.CriaCompra();
                dao.Update(compra);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Estoque = estoqueDAO.Lista();
                ViewBag.Fornecedores = fornecedoresDAO.Lista();
                return View("FormUpdate", viewModel);
            }
        }
```

A ideia do update é pega o valor já registrado e subtrair do valor total e adiciona o novo valor digitado mais o a quantia do estoque com subtração feita anteriormente, quando eu coloca o breakpoint na questão dos cálculos, ele faz tudo certo a equação de valores porém quando vai sobrepor a quantia que já estava no estoque e por a nova ele não sobrepõem.

Adicionar(Aqui ele faz a mesma equação e salva normalmente no estoque):

```
var Consulta = ckm.ControleEstoque(viewModel.ProdutoId);
            var Estoque = Consulta.OrderBy(t => t.NomeProduto).FirstOrDefault();

            int quantidadefinal = Estoque.Quantidade + viewModel.Quant;

            Estoque.Quantidade = quantidadefinal;
```

Comment: Não entendi. Está funcionando ou não o update? O problema está na atualização dos valores na controller ou no banco? Mostre como está salvando a transação.

Comment: Os valores e o calculo que efetua está tudo okay, o problema é que no final ele não transfere o novo valor que é `QuantidadeFinal` para o `Estoque.Quantidade`

Comment: entity ? tá salvando ?

Comment: Precisamos saber como está salvando o objeto no banco

Comment: Estou usando NHibernate para fazer a conexão com o banco

Comment: na linha `Estoque.Quantidade = quantidadefinal;` ele passa o valor para a propriedade `Estoque.Quantidade`?. coloque o código de `Update`

Comment: @Barbetta pronto

Comment: Não consegui identificar ali no código onde você da `update` no objeto `Estoque`. é ele que você está tentando alterar, certo?

Comment: Parece que o update é realizado no `dao.Update(compra);`. Verifique se o objeto `compra` está com as informações corretas.